# How many 5-digit numbers are multiples of 5 and 8?

Tags: contest-math

Please help me with this question that I have been stuck on. It is an APMOPS question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all multiples of $40$ from $10000$ to $100000$(remove $100000$).

$2500-250=2250$.

Comment: not sure you need to subtract 1

Comment: You should not substract 1 as it will also 10000

Answer (score 0):

First 5 digit number divisible by 5 is 10000. And last 5 digit number divisible by 5 is 99995. So you can find the total 5 digit numbers divisible by 5 which are 18000.

Similarly for 8 first is 10000 and last is 99992. So total are 11250.

Now numbers divisible by both 5 and 8 i.e by 40 are counted twice so 5. Digit numbers by 40 are (doing in similar way) are 2250.

So total 5 digit numbers divisible by 5 and 8 are

$18000+11250-2250=27000$

Comment: The answer i of numbers divisible by either 5 or 8 or by both. You haven't mentioned it in your question .